# Pass the username and password in Authorization headers for OData

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

How to pass the username and password in Authorization headers for OData URL in Asp.net core 2.2

Answer (score 1):

Use an `HTTPClient` where you can set the specific header value for authorization:

```
string username = "bbb";
string password = "abc";
string url = "https://yourOData.com"

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient .DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));

HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.GetAsync(url);
```

If you got that one working, take a look at https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/  and refactor your code to not instantiate HttpClient in the way I did.

Comment: actually i am new to OData ..so can you please give an example as where Odata url  has to pass in your above code...please help me out...thank in advance ....